# View Closed/Deleted Questions?

Tags: support

Is there a `Question` view for `Closed` or `Deleted` Questions? Do I just need more privilege to unlock this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While searching for topics you can use advanced search tips like this:

> is:question deleted:no closed:yes

There is a feature regarding deleted questions:

> Only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content

[image]

Comment: A note: using `deleted:*` only works for users with 10k and above.